# In EditText typed-text missing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an **editText** , the text typed in **ediText** is `not showing-up` until `back key` is pressed means when am typing it shows nothing.

and my editText is in `ScrollView.`

Phone am using is of size `240*320 (QVGA)`.

how to resolve this weird-issue..

**edited:**In `scrollView there is a LinearLayout . In LinearLayout having editText`

```
after back press i can see what i typed.
```

Thanks...

Comment: Share your layout details of the EditText.

Comment: how do u recognize that what u typed?